# Making HTTP requests with facebook webhooks

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to make a simple movie subtitling using Messenger bots. I have done most of but, but stuck on this part.

Okay so, here's the message flow

`User sends message -> e.g "hi" -> server makes a http request to my database and return the "hi" meaning. -> send the message back`

Okay so to handle all this, i have:

```
    // handler receiving messages
app.post('/webhook', function (req, res) {
    var events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        if (event.message && event.message.text) {
           if (hasWhiteSpace(event.message.text)) {
                console.log("hi");
                sendMessage(event.sender.id, {text: "Whitespace please try again"});
            }  else {

                 sendMessage(event.sender.id, {text: "wait..."});
                  var url = 'http://subtitlebuddy.com/api/res/index.php?word=' + event.message.text ;
                      console.log(url)


                // Return new promise 
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                     // Do async job


                        http.get(url, function(res){
                        var body = '';

                        res.on('data', function(chunk){
                            body += chunk;
                        });

                        res.on('end', function(){
                            var fbResponse = JSON.parse(body);

                            sendMessage(event.sender.id, {text: event.message.text + ": " + fbResponse.meaning});
                            //console.log("Got a response: ", fbResponse.meaning);
                        });
                    }).on('error', function(e){
                          console.log("Got an error: ", e);
                    }); 
                    })

            }

        }
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

My `sendMessage()` function:

```
    // generic function sending messages
function sendMessage(recipientId, message) {
    request({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
        qs: {access_token: process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN},
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            recipient: {id: recipientId},
            message: message,
        }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
        } else if (response.body.error) {
            console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
        }
    });
};
```

For the record my website subtitlebuddy.com is fast, i tried it on my browser. But when the user sends a message without whitespaces, i should get the meaning but **all i get "wait" 10 to 12 times**. I don't know what i am doing wrong,

Thanks

Edit. this is how i check for whitespaces:

```
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return /\s/g.test(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [www.valentinog.com's](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/http-requests-node-js-async-await/) tutorial, i used axios and it works perfectly now